# XSL1.0 Generate Ascending Seq #

Tags: xslt

I'm using XSL1.0. My editor/debugger is OxygenXML with Saxon (OxygenXML can't debug with MSXML) and it will deployed to work with a 3rd party app that only uses MSXML. This means I can't use a variable containing a nodeset if I want to be able to debug.

The problem could *probably* be expressed as how to sequentially number output of the following  -

```
<xsl:for-each select="node1">
   <xsl:variable name="current_ID" select="ID">
     <xsl:for-each select="sub_node1">
       <xsl:value-of select="../ID"/>-<xsl:value-of select="Sub_ID"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

understanding that I cannot simply use this in my scenario:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="node1/sub_node1">
       <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Below is a manufactured example that shows the problem I'm trying to solve as part of a much larger XSL/XML combo. I basically need to create manufacturing instructions. All nodes in the XML with the exception of products/versions (by qty) are in the correct order and I cannot change it. I need to generate the same set of sequential numbers from 3 different XSL's. My current context will always be shipments/deliveries/delivery_products (i.e. my XSL has to process the nodes in the seq shown). I need to produce a list of products sorted by version qty and their deliveries. Each row should have a sequential no (1-4) in example below

```
<shipments>
<product>
    <name>Product 1</name>
    <prod_id>P1</prod_id>
    <version>
        <version_id>P1_V1</version_id>
        <qty>8800</qty>
    </version>
    <version>
        <version_id>P1_V2</version_id>
        <qty>1100</qty>
    </version>
    <version>
        <version_id>P1_V3</version_id>
        <qty>100</qty>
    </version>
</product>
<product>
    <name>Product 2</name>
    <prod_id>P2</prod_id>
    <version>
        <version_id>P2_V1</version_id>
        <qty>5000</qty>
    </version>
    <version>
        <version_id>P2_V2</version_id>
        <qty>5000</qty>
    </version>
    <version>
        <version_id>P2_V3</version_id>
        <qty>2000</qty>
    </version>
</product>
<deliveries>
    <del_id>1</del_id>
    <destination>Miami</destination>
    <delivery_products>
        <version_id>P1_V1</version_id>
        <qty>8000</qty>
    </delivery_products>
    <delivery_products>
        <version_id>P2_V1</version_id>
        <qty>5000</qty>
    </delivery_products>
</deliveries>
<deliveries>
    <del_id>2</del_id>
    <destination>New York</destination>
    <delivery_products>
        <version_id>P1_V1</version_id>
        <qty>800</qty>
    </delivery_products>
    <delivery_products>
        <version_id>P2_V2</version_id>
        <qty>1000</qty>
    </delivery_products>
</deliveries>
```

Expected output is below. Note seq # starts from 1 and counts up to 4

```
    <table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
       <td class="col_head">
          Seq  
       </td>
       <td class="col_head">
          Version
       </td>
       <td class="col_head">
          Destination
       </td>
       <td class="col_head">
          Qty
       </td>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="rev_heading">Product 1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>P1_V1</td>
    <td>Miami</td>
    <td>8000</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>P1_V1</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>800</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="rev_heading">Product 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>P2_V1</td>
    <td>Miami</td>
    <td>5000</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>P2_V2</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>5000</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Here's my XSL so far (just stuck a position() in for a place holder for the seq #)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>

   <xsl:template match="shipments">    
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Seq Test</title>

        <style type="text/css">
        table {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
        td {border: 1px solid black; padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px;}
        .col_head {font-weight: 600;}
        .rev_heading {color: red; text-align: center; padding-top: 15px;}
       </style>
      </head>
      <body>

       <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <!-- SEQ# -->
              <td class="col_head">
                Seq
              </td>
              <!-- Imprint/Version -->
              <td class="col_head">
                Version
              </td>
              <!-- Ship to -->
              <td class="col_head">
                Destination
              </td>
              <!-- Qty -->
              <td class="col_head">
                Qty
              </td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <xsl:for-each select="product">
            <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="qty"/>
              <xsl:for-each select="version">
                <xsl:variable name="curr_version" select="version_id"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1"> 
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" class="rev_heading">                                
                        <xsl:value-of select="../name"/>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:for-each select="../../deliveries/delivery_products[version_id = $curr_version]">
                  <tr >
                    <!-- SEQ# -->
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Version -->
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="version_id"/>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Ship to -->
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="../destination"/>
                    </td>
                    <!-- QTY -->
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="qty"/>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
              </xsl:for-each> 
              </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using XSL1.0. My editor/debugger is OxygenXML with Saxon
>   (OxygenXML can't debug with MSXML) and it will deployed to work with a
>   3rd party app that only uses MSXML. This means I can't use a variable
>   containing a nodeset if I want to be able to debug.

**You can still use oXygen and the EXSLT `node-set()` function**.

When you are finished, simply change the namespace-uri from `"http://exslt.org/common"` to `"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"`

**Here is a short example of this technique**. Suppose you are finished debugging the below transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="num[. mod 3 = 0]"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:copy-of select="sum(ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)/*)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Then you make the change from the EXSLT namespace-uri to the MSXSL namespace uri:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="num[. mod 3 = 0]"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:copy-of select="sum(ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)/*)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Finally, you run this last transformation with MSXML and it produces exactly the same result as the initial transformation that uses EXSLT**:

```
18
```

Comment: Could you explain this line:

<xsl:copy-of select="sum(ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)/*)"/>

Regards

Comment: @mark1234, The expression in the `select` attribute is evaluated and then the result of this evaluation is copied to the output (because we want to see and verify it is correct). As for: `sum(ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)/*)` -- the inner sub-expression converts the RTF (Result Tree Fragment) value of `$vrtfPass1` to a normal tree, which we can inspect using XPath. The infamous RTF type prohibits any useful XPath evaluation against it (except using its string value, no inner nodes can be accessed). All XSLT 1.0 processors have the xxx:node-set() extension to convert this to a regular tree to access